# undefined symbol: std::string when linking static library in VS 2017

Tags: c++, linker, c++14, static-libraries, static-linking

I need to link static library to my main project in VS2017. I have included the lib file and compile my main project using Gnu++14. Both of the main project and the static library are in C++. The problem is I don't have information how this static library is built. Then I got these undefined symbol errors related to `std::string` and `std::basic_string` when compiling my main project.

```
Error       undefined symbol: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)        
Error       undefined symbol: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)
Error       undefined symbol: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()   
Error       undefined symbol: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)   
Error       undefined symbol: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)
Error       undefined symbol: std::string::assign(std::string const&)
Error       undefined symbol: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)
Error       undefined symbol: std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage
```

I suspect the static library is built differently (maybe clang), but I am not sure. Any lead about the possible cause of this error or possible solution?

Comment: You can't mix different tool-chains like that.  Until very recently you couldn't even mix versions within the same tool-chain.

Comment: Have you maybe touched the *Standard library* lib path?

Comment: @RichardCritten can you give me the example of mix tool chains that you mentioned?

Comment: @Wolf yes, the path is not a problem

Comment: "_...link static library to my main project in VS2017..."_ and _"...I suspect the static library is built differently (maybe clang), ..."_ mixing tool-chains - it will never work.

Comment: It means that if the library was built by MSVC then in no way can you statically link it with library built by Gnu++14 or whatever else - even using a different version of MSVC might cause code corruption. You can link with a dll that has C style API that was built by a different toolchain/language but not with a static library.

Comment: @ALX23z thanks for the hint, so let's say if the library is built using Clang/LLVM that originally target Android, then I can't link it with my main program that is built using Gnu++, right?

Comment: @gameon67 -- What if the internals of the `std::string` class is different among compiler and compiler versions?  So of course you can't mix things up, because the internals are different.  The public interface is the same amongst compilers, but what's inside could be radically different.

Comment: ***MSVC might cause code corruption*** Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 are binary compatible but not compatible with any other version of msvc. I believe they are not compatible with gcc / mingw when compiling c++ code but there is a way to obtain some clang compatibility.

Comment: Related: [https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html#msvc-compatibility](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html#msvc-compatibility)

Comment: Also: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)